# Two x-rays, 11 o'clock

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Call of Duty, Modern Warfare 2, Captain Price asks Yuri to shoot two men using his sniper rifle. He first draws Yuri's attention to their location by saying, "Two x-rays, 11 o'clock." And then commands to kill those, "Take them out." I don't understand x-rays here! I googled it so many times but got nothing. It wasn't dark and they weren't wearing night vision goggles, so that possibility is also out. Anyone is familiar with such term and it's usage here?

Comment: You may wish to refer to [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87634/what-is-an-x-ray).

Comment: See also: American soldiers referred to the [Viet Cong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viet_Cong#Names) by the abbreviations 'Victor Charlie' or 'V-C', while 'Charlie' was used for Communist forces in general.

Comment: In case any English learners are confused, "11 o'clock" in a military context means "slightly to the left of where you are facing", and "12 o'clock" would mean "straight ahead".

Comment: Duplicate [question on Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87634). Means unidentified target is very slightly left of straight ahead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In context it's clear that by "X-ray" they mean "possible enemies" or "possible targets".  It's *military slang*.

The question is, why "X-ray"?  This is most likely related to the [military phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), in which X-RAY stands for the letter "X".  "X" is commonly used in English to refer to "unidentified" or "secret" objects (and so sounds vaguely "cool"), but in this case it's *possible* that 'X" stands for "eXtremist" -- meaning "rogue" soldiers who are not part of any official state-sponsored military.

In a similar way, certain militaries (or at least, games supposedly based on the military) use "Tango" to refer to certain enemies.  TANGO is the military phonetic term for the letter "T", which may refer to "terrorist" or "target".

Note that in other games "X-ray" might refer to "eXtraterrestrials", meaning *aliens*.

Comment: I've heard the term "X-ray" from friends in the military, and they confirm that there's no real single, defined meaning -- it means what Tango and Victor Charlie did: Enemy. Sure, there's some reason behind it (eXtremist according to one, X on a map according to another, Target, VietCong, etc.) but it's not really used as an abbreviation _for_ that.

Comment: @NicHartley  Sure, that makes sense.  Military slang is like any other slang -- each new generation needs to make up its own to distinguish themselves from the "old guard".  Also like most slang, I expect an original source exists, but is often unknown by the people who use it.

Comment: The use of "Tango" for "enemy" predates concerns with terrorism by some time.

Comment: @chrylis  "Tango" for "target", perhaps?  Although it might just be a movie / video game thing, as apparently actually military personnel don't ever use it.  They have other slang terms for enemy combatants.  One thing I've learned, hanging around Marines, is not to assume anything I've seen in movies.

Comment: As an aside, I have heard of the bull's eye of a shooting target described as the X-ring (this would be inside the "10"-ring)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiservice_tactical_brevity_code. No X-Ray (or Tango), but it does have Bogey and Bandit (for aircraft).

Comment: @RogerLipscombe That may be out of date.  Military slang is (apparently) constantly evolving.   For example [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Military/comments/nc3z1/if_tango_means_hostile_target_and_victor_means/) includes a few comments from self-identified US military.

Answer (score 8):

X-ray is the phonetic pronunciation of the letter X in military speak. Basically just preventing miscommunication over noisy channels. This may just be Call of Duty being Call of Duty and trying to sprinkle as much military speak as possible into the game. Check out this:
[wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)

Comment: "X-Ray just means X" isn't really any help understanding the sentence.  Okay, well what does "X" mean?